# problem generating xml signature with python

Tags: python, xml, sign

I want to sign the following xml called example.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
  <Ficha version="1.0">
    <Documento ID="F1">
      <Animal>
       <tipo>33</Tipo>
       <raza>1</raza>
       <Fch>2021-02-22</Fch>
     </Animal>
  </Documento>
</Ficha>
```

I use the following code in python

```
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier
import signxml
import sys

file='example.xml'
uri='F1'
ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='ISO-8859-1', resolve_entities=False)
el = ET.parse(file,parser)
root = el.getroot()
cert = open("cert.pem").read()
key = open("key.pem").read()

signed_root = XMLSigner(method=signxml.methods.enveloped,
                        signature_algorithm='rsa-sha1',
                        c14n_algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315',
                        digest_algorithm="sha1").sign(root, key=key,cert=cert,reference_uri=uri,always_add_key_value=True)

tree = ET.ElementTree(signed_root)
```

generates the signature but ...
the resulting xml file is

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
    <Ficha xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" version="1.0">
        <Documento ID="F1">
                <Animal>
                    <tipo>33</Tipo>
                    <raza>1</raza>
                    <Fch>2021-02-22</Fch>
                </Animal>
    </Documento>
    <Signature>
         .....
         .....
         .....
    </Signature>
    </Ficha>
```

and what I want is:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
        <Ficha version="1.0">
            <Documento ID="F1">
                    <Animal>
                        <tipo>33</Tipo>
                        <raza>1</raza>
                        <Fch>2021-02-22</Fch>
                    </Animal>
        </Documento>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
             .....
             .....
             .....
        </Signature>
        </Ficha>
```

what am i doing wrong I need to change the attribute **xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"**
from the ficha tag to the signature tag

Answer (score 0):

Ficha is your root element and I think you are specifically calling sign on the root element by using .sign(root,.....

I would give the signature element a variable name and replace

.sign(root...

with

.sign(signature_variable...